# Hamburger menu not toggling in vue-nuxt project

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I tried to create a navbar like this in vue-nuxt

```
<template>
  <div class="navbar-padding">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <img
        :src="navImage"
        width="60"
        height="60"
        class="d-inline-block align-top customo-logo"
        alt="company-logo"
      />
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li
            v-for="(el, index) in links"
            :key="'item_' + index"
            class="navbar-li"
          >
            <a class="navbar-text-right" href="/">{{ el.label }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

This does show the navbar as expected but on mobile, when I click on it, the hamburger does not toggle the menu

This is my nuxt config file

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css", href: "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
      // SCSS file in the project
    '@/assets/css/common.scss',
    '@/assets/css/button.scss',
    '@/assets/css/navbar.scss',
  ],
  script: [
    { src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' },
    { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js' },
    { src: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js' }
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    'nuxt-fontawesome'

  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: problem might be that the automatic initialization of bootstrap component is not working if used in a vue component, you might want to initialize it yourself in 
`mounted()` lifecycle hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to **move** the `script` array inside your `head` object:

```js
head: {
  title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
  meta: [
    { charset: 'utf-8' },
    { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
    { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
  ],
  script: [
    { src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' },
    { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js' },
    { src: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js' }
  ],
  link: [
    { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
    {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      type: 'text/css',
      href: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    }
  ]
},
```

See how to use external resources at [Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/#global-settings)